# How do I configure the wires in the LVDS 30 pin cable?

Tags: lcd, pins, lvds, monitor

I explain: 
I have a screen that I want to use as a [image]monitor. I have purchased an LCD controller board and a LVDS cable
I need someone to help me to rewire the LVDS cable. I have the input terminal pin assignment for the monitor and also the pinout for the controller, but the outputs/inputs are completely different in each. I hope maybe someone could help match them. Once I know what goes where, I can rewire the 30-pin cable.
The images are from the controller on the left and the monitor on the right.
How do I configure the wires in the LVDS 30 pin cable?
Thanks.
Edit:
OK, I did it the way Natsu Sake told me. I added a new picture with the results.
[image: Final wiring]

Comment: 7 & 8 on left go to 1 & 2 on right, etc. .... just match up the signal names

Comment: Hello there. The basic method of matching the two tables is this: TX00-  ->  RXIn00-   TX00+  ->  RXIn00+ and so on. The last three characters need to be matched (XX±).   The VSel is the one to go to Vdd.

Comment: @Natsu Kage, thanks I will try your way. I will comment later.

Comment: @Natsu Kage, hi again. Do you think it is OK like this?

Comment: Your last edit should have been posted *as an answer*, and **not** in the question. Please [edit] your question to remove the solution, post it as an answer and then mark it as the accepted answer - in order to mark it as an answered question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are asking, and I am not really familiarized with LVDS cables, but you need to rewire.

I see two solutions:

1. If you can rewire at least one of the connector ends:

   Disconnect everything from that end, with a multimeter probe for continuity from the end that is still wired to the loose cables on the other end, and go wiring one by one, matching the names on the list you posted.
2. If you can't rewire at least one of the connector ends:

   You need to cut cables in half and repeat process one but with both ends, soldering one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but, I´m going to try the way Natsu Kage told me. I believe it is easier. Thanks again.