# I have 2 LCD panels - I'm trying to find out what electronics I need to set them up

Tags: lcd, monitor, panel

I have two LCD panels that I want to use, but they don't have any electronics, case or anything with them (I got them from a computer shop that was shutting down).

I need to figure out what PCB they need and what plug / power supply, etc., I need for them.

The serial numbers for them are:

- [M240HTN01.2](https://www.panelook.com/M240HTN01.2_AUO_24.0_LCM_overview_20529.html)
- [HSD250MUW2-A00](https://www.panelook.com/HSD250MUW2-A00_HannStar_24.5_LCM_overview_3231.html)

I'm able to find information on them well enough, but when it comes to finding out how to get them working - I'm stuck.

My abilities with electronics is very basic.

I would really appreciate the help and direction of anyone here that can help me.

Comment: For what you want to use them?

Comment: For my PC. I want the extra monitors for my desktop setup.

Comment: Since you are a beginner in electronics, I think that this is too much for you to take on. Even experienced guys would be scratching their heads with how to go about this.

Comment: Really, don't bother. My local thrift store sells 24 inch 1080's for $20. You're going to have to find a display controller, backlight driver, and a power supply, and that's going to cost you 2-3x that, minimum.

Comment: Aw...really? Dang...I was hoping it would be as easy as finding the right pcb control unit...so what should I do with them if there's no point trying to get them working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With experience, it isn't at all particularly difficult.

Looking at the links that you have found, the interface, on both of the panels, is listed as LVDS, so you would need an *LVDS controller board*, and an *LVDS cable*.

Then you might need to wire them up appropriately - see [How do I configure the wires in the LVDS 30 pin cable?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/477855/64015) for an insight as to what would be required.

Once connected, you might need to configure the controller board to display images correctly on the panels.

A basic example showing how to connect an LVDS panel to a Pi is here, [How to Connect Raspberry Pi to a Laptop LCD Panel via LVDS/LCD Controller Board](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0IiXl88Sfw).

---

Basically, make sure that the LVDS board that you buy comes with a cable that has a connector that will fit your display panel - otherwise you'll have to rewire it (as per the link I posted), which is best avoided if possible. Check that the number of pins on the connector of the cable is the same as the connector on your panel, and hopefully it should just be plug and play!

An example of making an incorrect initial purchase of an LVDS board is described here, [Using a laptop screen as a monitor](https://www.bestsoldering.com/using-a-laptop-screen-as-a-monitor/).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the answer I was looking for. 

I may not be that up on electronics, but I did build myself a guitar pedal that worked from a vero board and trans/resistors etc so I can learn.

So do I need to learn about LVDS controllers, are they all the same (doubt it) or do I have to find the right one for this monitor type? 

Judging by the YouTube video you posted, it's  a matter of finding the right controllers and cables, right PSU and then connecting it to my computer once it's all set up properly.

Am I on the right track there? 

Again - thank you!